# Preserve #pragma indentations in C/C++ VSCode

Tags: c, openmp, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using the Google format setting for auto format my C/C++ code

```
 "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google,
 IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}"
```

However the autoformat changes my indentation from this:

```
#pragma omp task            \
firstprivate(i,x,y,board)   \
shared(n, a)                \
private(m,n)
```

into this:

```
#pragma omp task                  \
    firstprivate(i, x, y, board) \
        shared(n, a) private(m, n)
```

I want to preserve the indentation, how can I achieve this ?